# Volume of high-dimensional sphere vs volume of sphere's shell

Tags: statistical-mechanics, integration, phase-space, volume

When calculating the phase space volume $\Omega$ in the microcanoncial ensemble with fixed energy $E$, one integrates over a shell that includes all energies in between $E$ and $E+\delta E$:

$$\Omega=\int\int_{E<H(p,q)<E+\delta E} ~ ~\mathrm{d}^{3N}q\mathrm{d}^{3N}p$$

The volume of a $d$-dimensional sphere with radius R [is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere)

$$V_d(r=R)=\frac{\pi^{d/2}}{\Gamma\left(\frac{d}{2}+1\right)}R^d$$

A shell of this $d$-dimensional sphere with thickness $\Delta r$ has the volume

$$V'_d=\frac{\pi^{d/2}}{\Gamma\left(\frac{d}{2}+1\right)}\left(R^d-(\Delta r)^d\right)$$

So if the shell has thickness $\Delta r=\frac{R}{2^{1/d}}$ it occupies the same volume $V'_d=V_d(r=\Delta r)$ as a sphere with radius $\Delta r$. If we assume many particles $N$, the dimension of the phase space goes $d\to\infty$ and so the ratio of the spheres volume and the volume of the small shell goes to 1.

$$\lim_{d\to\infty}\Delta r=\lim_{d\to\infty} \frac{R}{2^{1/d}}=R $$

Under these assumptions: Is it appropriate to just use the volume of the whole sphere instead of the shell volume in high dimensions / for many particles? If not, where is my error?

Answer (score 2):

The volume of a $N$-sphere is proportional to $R^N$ then the volume of the spherical shell of thickness $dR$ would be proportional to $R^N-(R-dR)^N=R^N(1-(1-dR/R)^N)$, assuming $dR<<R$ but $N(dR)>>R$ you can approximate
\begin{equation}
(1-dR/R)^N\simeq\exp{(-dR/R)^N}=\exp{(-NdR/R)}\simeq0.
\end{equation}

Then the volume of the shell is approximately proportional to $R^N$ and this is better approximated if $N$ tends to infinity.